# How to run multiple laravel projects of different php version on macOs catalina and i m using valet and nginx?

Tags: php, laravel-8, macos-catalina, laravel-valet

[image: when i ran the command brew link php]

i have two laravel projects one is using php 8 and another is using php 7.1 how to run both the projects on macOs and i m using valet and nginx.
thanks in advance